# I have a text file that is one long line of text that I want to break up into a dictionary, how would I do that?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that looks like this, where the line that starts "Distance IQC/E: Distance XY" and the rest the follows is one long line until :END:

```
:BEGIN
"Distance IQC/E: Distance XY",0.09066,0.09060,0.00040,0.00040,0.00006,,"Distance IQC/F: Distance XY",0.14603,0.14590,0.00080,0.00080,0.00013,,"Distance IQC/G: Distance XY",0.12074,0.12070,0.00080,0.00080,0.00004,,"Distance IQC/I: Distance XY",0.21476,0.21600,0.00200,0.00200,-0.00124,,"Distance IQC/H: Distance XY",0.12714,0.12760,0.00080,0.00080,-0.00046,,"Distance IQC/N: Distance XY",0.08661,0.08690,0.00080,0.00080,-0.00029,,"Distance IQC/M: Distance XY",0.12997,0.13000,0.00080,0.00080,-0.00003,
:END
```

I want to know how to split this text file so that each line starts with a "Distance" and is followed by the remaining floaters until the next "Distance".

I can use file.replace(":BEGIN","") to get rid of the Begin and End.

Do I make a dictionary and then rewrite that dictionary to a new text file?

Please help I'm a very new programmer!

Edit: I would expect the output to be:

```
Distance IQC/E: Distance XY 0.09066 0.09060 0.00040 0.00040 0.00006  
Distance IQC/F: Distance XY 0.14603 0.14590 0.00080 0.00080 0.00013  
Distance IQC/G: Distance XY 0.12074 0.12070 0.00080 0.00080 0.00004  
Distance IQC/I: Distance XY 0.21476 0.21600 0.00200 0.00200 -0.00124  
Distance IQC/H: Distance XY 0.12714 0.12760 0.00080 0.00080 -0.00046  
Distance IQC/N: Distance XY 0.08661 0.08690 0.00080 0.00080 -0.00029  
Distance IQC/M: Distance XY 0.12997 0.13000 0.00080 0.00080 -0.00003
```

This way I could archive the data cleanly into an excel file or something similar.

edit 2:

Here is the small bit of code I have so far:

```
with open("file.txt","r") as read_data:
    f=read_data.read().replace(":BEGIN",'').replace(":END",'')
```

Comment: You should read up on what makes a [mcve] - if you want code, you need to show us what you've got so far and what's not working. It's also probably necessary to include your desired output as well.

Comment: What do you want the keys to be? What do you want the values to be? Please provide an example of your expected output.

Comment: No need for a dictionary just to insert newlines: `astr = big_str.replace("Distance", "\nDistance")`

Comment: cdarke, you beautiful genius

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is your input data:

```
line = ':BEGIN\n"Distance IQC/E: Distance XY",0.09066,0.09060,0.00040,0.00040,0.00006,,"Distance IQC/F: Distance XY",0.14603,0.14590,0.00080,0.00080,0.00013,,"Distance IQC/G: Distance XY",0.12074,0.12070,0.00080,0.00080,0.00004,,"Distance IQC/I: Distance XY",0.21476,0.21600,0.00200,0.00200,-0.00124,,"Distance IQC/H: Distance XY",0.12714,0.12760,0.00080,0.00080,-0.00046,,"Distance IQC/N: Distance XY",0.08661,0.08690,0.00080,0.00080,-0.00029,,"Distance IQC/M: Distance XY",0.12997,0.13000,0.00080,0.00080,-0.00003,\n:END'
```

Then, as you said, you could first get rid of the BEGIN and END.

```
data = line.replace(':BEGIN\n', '')
data = line.replace(',\n:END', '')
```

And then split the rest of the data into lines using two commas as separator.

```
data_list = data.split(',,')
```

Finally, you can create your dictionary by splitting each line with commas as separators. The first element of the list could be the key (including the quotation marks in this case). For the value, you could group them into a list.

```
data_dict = dict()

for data_element in data_list:
    element_as_list = data_element.split(',')
    key = element_as_list[0]
    value = element_as_list[1:]

    data_dict[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'Distance IQC/E: Distance XY",0.09066,0.09060,0.00040,0.00040,0.00006,,"Distance IQC/F: Distance XY",0.14603,0.14590,0.00080,0.00080,0.00013,,"Distance IQC/G: Distance XY",0.12074,0.12070,0.00080,0.00080,0.00004,,"Distance IQC/I: Distance XY",0.21476,0.21600,0.00200,0.00200,-0.00124,,"Distance IQC/H: Distance XY",0.12714,0.12760,0.00080,0.00080,-0.00046,,"Distance IQC/N: Distance XY",0.08661,0.08690,0.00080,0.00080,-0.00029,,"Distance IQC/M: Distance XY",0.12997,0.13000,0.00080,0.00080,-0.00003,'

sub_str = str.split(',,')
temp_arr = []

for i in sub_str:
    temp_arr.append(i.split(','))

for i in temp_arr:
    str_i = ' '.join(i)
    print(str_i)
```

This would solve the problem.